# Concatenating irregular lists in python dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary with 2 lists like below

```
dict_ans={'Car':[['Toyota', 'Honda'], ['Ford','GM']],
          'Truck':['Kenworth', 'Mack']
         }
```

I am trying to get it in the format below:

```
dict_ans={'Car':['Toyota', 'Honda','Ford','GM'],
          'Truck':['Kenworth','Mack']
         }
```

I tried a few options in the link https://stackabuse.com/python-how-to-flatten-list-of-lists
But in each case the `'Truck'` resolves to `['K','e','n','w','o','r','t','h','M','a','c','k']`
The `Car` entry worked fine.
Any thoughts on the best way to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: You could check the element type prior to flattening. If the list contains lists, flatten, otherwise don't.

Comment: Include the code you tried _as a part of your question_, not as a link to an external site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dictionary comprehension with `numpy.hstack`

```
import numpy as np

new_dict = {k:np.hstack(v).tolist() for k,v in dict_ans.items()} 
# {'Car': ['Toyota', 'Honda', 'Ford', 'GM'], 'Truck': ['Kenworth', 'Mack']}
```

Comment: You don't need to rebuild the dict or even rebind the values, since lists are mutable. `for v in dict_ans.values(): v[:] = np.hstack(v)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a custom function and `dict` comprehension?

```
def flatten(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return [a for i in x for a in flatten(i)]
    else:
        return [x]
>>> {k: flatten(dict_ans[k]) for k in dict_ans}
{'Car': ['ToyotaHonda', 'Ford', 'GM'], 'Truck': ['Kenworth', 'Mack']}
```